# php is not connecting with mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to perform a query on a database with genomic information.

This is part of the php code:

```
$db = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database)

$fields = "name, chrom, strand, txStart, txEnd, exonCount, name2";
$query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table WHERE name2 LIKE '%$gene%';";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
$items = mysqli_affected_rows($result);


if ($items == 0)

{
  print_error("The gene $gene is not found in the RefSeq database");
}
else 
{
  $transcripts = $items;

  echo "<html>\n";
  echo "<head>\n";
  echo "<title> Catalogue web server </title>\n";
  echo "<link href=\"styles.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">\n";
  echo "</head>\n";
  echo "<body>\n";
  echo "<h1>Catalogue output ($gene)</h1>\n";

  echo "<table>\n";
  echo "<tr><th>GENE</th><th>TRANSCRIPTS</th><th>CHR</th><th>STRAND</th><th>POS1</th><th>POS2</th><th>EXONS</th>\n";

  for ($i = 0; $i<$items; $i++)
  {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $name2 = $row["name2"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $chrom = $row["chrom"];
    $strand = $row["strand"];
    $txStart = $row["txStart"];
    $txEnd = $row["txEnd"];
    $exonCount = $row["exonCount"];

    echo "<tr><td>$name2</td><td>$name</td><td>$chrom</td><td>$strand</td><td>$txStart</td><td>$txEnd</td><td>$exonCount</td>\n";
  }
  echo"</table><br><br>\n";
}
```

However, when I submit the query from html localhost, I´m always getting the error message:

```
The gene is not in the database
```

When I know it is.

Any help finding the error would be appreciated it.

ALSO: $servername, $username, $password and $database are correct, checked several times

I don´t mind about mysql injections as I´m not publishing this web

Comment: *The gene is not in the database* is not in the provided code, if you meant *The gene  is not found in the RefSeq database*, then `$gene` is not defined, you should enable actual error reporting

Comment: Try checking the contents of $result first: `var_dump($result);` and if that is not FALSE, then: `var_dump(mysqli_fetch_row($result));`

Comment: Thx rkok, indeed the result to var_dump($result) was false. Let´s see what i can do

Answer (score 1):

Try instead with:

```
$items = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

The `mysqli_affected_rows` is used after insert, update, replace or delete queries.

Comment: Thx Paul, but just changing that I got the same result

Comment: Where is `$table` defined, and `$gene` for that matter as a gene name is missing in the output message?

Comment: echo the query, copy it and try to run it directly on sql . Your code is ok, my guess is its really not there.  Also try the query without sending the semi colon